# Autolayout subviews residing in separate xib

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, autolayout

In addition to what the title says

1. Main window has a container view to the left, call this mainContainerView (green background)
2. In a second .xib I have a NSTableView setup - call it Second.xib (red background)
3. In the MainViewController.m I add the NSTableView defined in Second.xib
   and set the constraint as the following

`[_mainContainerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_mainContainerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual toItem:self.second.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:0]];`

As you see in the screenshots, the red background does not follow the main container view when I resize the window. Do you know why this is happening?

[image: On startup before resizing]
[image: After resizing]

## Edit + Solved

In order to fix this error I had to set constraints for width/height. I also added constraints for top/bottom alignment to superview.
[image: After removing translationmask]

Comment: You have set a constraint that the container's bottom is *greater than or equal to* the table view's bottom. The result is consistent with that. If that's not what you want, then why did you use an inequality? The inequality allows the table view to stay shorter when the main window is made taller.

Comment: Actually setting it to equal does not allow the window to grow at all! i.e I cannot grow the height, only the width

Comment: In the xib containing your table view, I'm assuming the scroll view that encloses the table view is a top-level object (not a subview of any other view in the xib). If this is the case, look at the value of *Translates Mask Into Constraints* when the scroll view is selected. If it's checked, try unchecking it and see if this makes a difference.

Comment: @PaulPatterson see my edit. You can see a dot in the bottom left corner, seems that the size is 0? Edit2: I was missing constraints for height/width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer:

```
[_mainContainerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.second.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_mainContainerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.f constant:0.f]];
```

Comment: see my comment above, the window will stay at the same height without being able to increase it

Comment: @hajder Do you mean you want to set the whole window height fixed?

Comment: thanks for your reply but I have fixed it now by setting constraints on the height.

Comment: @hajder Cool! How about answer yourself then mark it?

Comment: thanks I marked your answer as the solution. In addition @Paul Patterson comment about unchecking the translation of masks into constraints was needed. Why?

Comment: @hajder If you don't uncheck it(`translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints `), `the view’s superview looks at the view’s autoresizing mask, produces constraints that implement it, and adds those constraints to itself (the superview).` as the document says.  In addition, have you watched any Auto Layout WWDC videos? They are very helpful for understand Auto Layout.

Comment: yes I've watched "Best Practices for Mastering Auto Layout".